# Makefile error - if else

Tags: unix, makefile

I have two question:
1) First: In a make file I am creating a file and setting its permission, but I assume that chmod is failing somehow

```
 72     chmod -R 777 $(DEL_LIB_PATH)
 73     ifeq ($?,1)
 74         echo "chmod failed"
 75     endif
```

On run the make file getting below error:

```
ifeq ($?,1)
ANOMALY: sh: syntax error at line 1 : `(' unexpected
ANOMALY: *** Error exit code 2
```

2) Second: My build take 1 hour and after that only errors comes due to error in make file, Is there any way / tools to check if make file is ok or not? without triggering the build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most fundamental aspect of writing makefiles to understand is the difference between the makefile syntax and the recipe syntax.  Makefiles are really two completely different languages combined into a single file.

All the "normal" parts of the makefile are in the makefile syntax described in the make manual.  However, the recipes (the lines indented by TAB characters after a target definition) are not makefile syntax, they are written in POSIX sh (shell) script: the `make` program will take the text that is indented by TAB characters, replace variable/function references (things started with a single `$`), then pass the entire thing to the shell to be processed and wait for the result (the exit code).  The *only* parsing of a recipe done by make is for variable/function references.  Nothing else.

So.  In your example above you are trying to use *makefile* constructs like `ifeq` inside a recipe, which requires *shell* constructs.  You can't do that and that's why you're getting syntax errors, *from the shell* (although your shell environment is weird... I've never seen one print `ANOMALY:` like that before).

You need to use *shell* constructs in a recipe; something like:

```
        chmod -R 777 $(DEL_LIB_PATH) ; \
        if [ $$? -eq 1 ]; then \
            echo "chmod failed"; \
        fi
```

Or, more succinctly:

```
        chmod -R 777 $(DEL_LIB_PATH) || echo "chmod failed"
```

However, this may be a bad idea because by doing this you're hiding the error from make.  The exit code of your recipe is now always success even if something fails.  Maybe that's what you want, but maybe not.  When working with recipes you must always be thinking carefully about how the recipe might fail and ensuring that if you want make to notice it, you are exiting with a non-0 error code.

I don't really know why you want to echo a message here anyway.  If the `chmod` fails it will print its own errors about why it failed: why not just let those message be enough, and simply use:

```
        chmod -R 777 $(DEL_LIB_PATH)
```

as your recipe?